# create-react-app reduce build size: main.[hash].chunk.js is 3MB+ with mostly images

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I build my app with `yarn build`.

It generate a 3.27MB `build\static\js\main.8dc5bf7f.chunk.js` file:

```
3.27 MB   build\static\js\main.8dc5bf7f.chunk.js
82.79 KB  build\static\js\2.61d04f1f.chunk.js
2 KB      build\static\css\main.275d97bd.chunk.css
1.93 KB   build\static\css\2.8380becc.chunk.css
768 B     build\static\js\runtime~main.848c2454.js

The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended.
Consider reducing it with code splitting
You can also analyze the project dependencies
```

I used `source-map-explorer` to analyze the file and it show:

[image]

So the file include all of the images of my entire app.

But funny thing is the build still have a `static/media` directory which has all of those images in .png form. And apparently the app still load those png files to show the images.

So what are those things in the js file? I wonder if they're even used at all?

Please:

- Explain to me why all of the images in my entire application is included in my logic javascript file.
- Is there anyway to remove them? I need to increase page load. 4MB at initial load is unbelievable.

Comment: It would be preferable to extract all of these images out and host them in a CDN, I believe huge chunk is not because you have huge images, it's because you have a lot of them as seen from the screenshot you included.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, anything you `import` in your app and handle bundling it with webpack would be considered as a dependency.

so: `import img from path/to/img` would make it a dependency, thus, included in your bundle, that's what you want to escape.

There are two possible scenarios to work-around this:

1. Stop importing images, make them available/hosted in a CDN such like AWS S3.
2. Apply a Move Statics Out approach, which is about moving all directories for static files out of the bundle, make them available in statics dependent folder and start using relative links instead, I would suggest [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).

For me, I would go with number 1.

Comment: Oh great I moved the whole thing to CDN and it's back to 100-ish KB now, wonderful! Also long live regex!

Comment: Wow, a hell of a ~reduction! great! ;)

Answer (score 12):

This is a tough problem that most engineers have as the app grows larger.

In your case you're importing a lot of small PNGs that get base64 encoded due to CRA's webpack setting. You can override that behavior with a library like [react-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). While it's a bit more involving process, I'd recommend that over maintaining an external image repository. It's easier to test and use in a development environment. Especially when offline.

I also see that most of your views are bundled together in main.js.

The secret to cutting down the bundle size is in leveraging code splitting and lazy loading.

Here's the link to the video that I put together for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8NJc60H294

In a nutshell, I suggest the following patterns:

### Code-split routes (if any)

This is commonly achieved by using `React.lazy()`

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
// import MyRoute from 'routes/MyRoute' - we are replacing this import

const MyRoute = lazy(() => import('routes/MyRoute'));

const Loading = () => <div>Loading route...</div>;

const View = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={Loading}>
    <MyRoute />
  </Suspense>
);
```

### Code-split low priority elements

Every page has Critical Path content. It's the content your visitors want to experience first. It's the primary purpose of a view. It's usually in the above the fold area (the part of the view they see when the page loads, without any scrolling).

However, that part can also be dissected based on priority. A Hero is a good critical path example, so we should prioritize it. A Hamburger menu is a great element to de-prioritize because it requires interaction to be viewed.

Anything below the fold can be de-prioritized too. A great example of this is Youtube comments. They only get loaded if we scroll down sufficiently.

You can follow the same principle as above to prioritize critical path content:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import Hero from 'component/Hero'

const Burger = lazy(() => import('components/Burger'));

// The fallback should be used to show content placeholders.
// It doesn't have to be a loading indicator.
const Loading = () => <img src="path/to/burger/icon" alt="Menu"/>;

const View = () => (
  <main>
    <Hero />
    <Suspense fallback={Loading}>
       <Burger />
    </Suspense>
  </main>
);
```

### Create abstract components for libraries

Following the principles above, I suggest creating simple abstract components for every library. Let's say you need animations and you use Framer Motion. You can import it in one place and use everywhere.

Many libraries ship with named exports and `lazy()` doesn't support that. I wrote a very simple library [react-lazy-named](https://github.com/grgur/react-lazy-named) that helps with that.

```
// AnimatedDiv.js

import React, { lazy } from 'react';

// This is similar to
//   import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
//   const Div = motion.div;
// Also, we hint webpack to use resource preloading (think service worker goodness)
const Div = lazy(() => import('framer-motion' /* webpackPreload: true */), 'motion.div'));

// Use regular div as a fallback.
// It will be replaced with framer-motion animated Div when lazy-loaded
const AnimatedDiv = (props) => (
  <Suspense fallback={<div>{props.children}</div>}>
    <Div {...props} />
  </Suspense>
);
```

If you have any questions or need and help with this you can reply here or in the comments of the aforementioned video on [Loading React apps in under 3 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8NJc60H294)

Answer (score 2):

Small image files will be loaded into your code when build with url-loader to reduce number of image requests. Large image files will be copied to build folder with file-loader.

Comment: ... um and? How do I move them all to the static folder?

Comment: You change url-loader to file-loader in webpack's config

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to be correct here, there are many files that appear in the js file and the static/media folder at the same time.

Comment: I'm using un-ejected create-react-app, so webpack config is not visible

Comment: You can try using public folder.
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack option `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT` to control which size of images will be put into the bundled js.

1. Create file `.env.production` at the root of project dir(same level with file package.json)
2. Add `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT=0` to this file, this tells webpack do not put any images into the js as base64 data. the default value is 10000, which will put images large than 10kb into js file.

[image]

To reduce to chunk js file size, take a look at `Code splitting` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html